# Background image position issue in android jelly Bean WebView

Tags: android, html, css, webview

background image position is not rendering in Jelly Bean webView, but works fine in KitKat version

**CSS**

```
    .clearable{
      background:url("../images/txtclear.png") no-repeat right 5px center !important;  
      border:1px solid #999;
      padding:3px 18px 3px 4px; 
      border-radius:3px; 
      transition: background 0.4s; 
    }
```

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<input value="" id="txtsearch" type="email" placeholder="Enter Search string" class="clearable"/>
</body>
</html>
```

i have also reffered to a similar post in the below URL, but this will not resolve my issue.
[background-attachment messes up rendering in Jelly Bean WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391179/background-attachment-messes-up-rendering-in-jelly-bean-webview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**background-position** with four-value syntax is only supported in Android 4.4 onwards, that's why it is not rendering properly.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-background-offsets

For those versions you could use a fallback rule in order to display properly. Just adjust % or px to match your item width and height.

```
.clearable{
   background-position: 95% 50%; /* Will apply only for < 4.4 */
   background-position: right 5px center;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Regards