# Loading GIF (Preloader) gets stuck only on Chrome - another perspective

Tags: html, css, image, gif, preloader

**I want the visitor to see the loading GIF as soon as he enters the website, until the the website has completely loaded and ready to go.**

HTML:

```
<img id = "firstLoadedImage" border="0" alt="title" src="Pictures/loading.gif" />
```

There is no CSS associated with this.

And I loaded every other image through my javascript document.ready call. This is the only occurance of declaring an image in HTML or CSS, beacuse I know that all the images are loaded together if I do that, but I only want this gif to load first.

But the problem still exists where in CHROME only, that there is a very noticeable delay before my gif image actually loads and starts to animate. I've extensively researched this and found the best matching solution, yet I tried their ways to find that it's somewhat a slightly different case from mine.  -   [Loading GIF (Preloader) gets stuck only on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982733/loading-gif-preloader-gets-stuck-only-on-chrome) -

The difference being that I'm using the GIF before the entire web page finished loading. I've tried dataURI with base64 already. It didn't work for me, as the same reasons from @amiregelz OP stated in his comments. So the only other solution is deleting the delcaration:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

But the only problem is that I never even used that code anywhere. So I guess the problem is now, what should I try next.

Any help from Guru's would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: link to jsfiddle would be appreciated

Comment: I don't have a jsfiddle sorry, but you can see the problem live @www.CharlesDing.com

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/KFpK5/

Comment: Use that for reference. That fiddle gif loads immediately, however I simply copied and pasted that into my code, and I would notice a delay where it doesn't load immediately.

Comment: Run www.CharlesDing.com on firefox and compare that to Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should be fixed now in the newer versions of chrome.