# CSS 3 specials rounded corners in borders

Tags: html, css, border

How can I realise this special corner in my border with CSS3

[image]

This is what I got now:

http://jsfiddle.net/hashie5/nDv5k/

```
<aside>
<h2>Product in de kijker</h2>
<h3>Mobiele telefonie</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-runa">Ga verder</a>
```

```
    aside {
    border: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
    width: 290px;
    margin: 50px;
}
body {
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 150%;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #1F668C;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #CCCC00;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-weight: normal;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #1E678E;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-weight: normal;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #1E668C;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-weight: normal;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #CCCC00;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.btn-runa {
    background: none;
    background-color: #CCCC00;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer this [jsFidde][1]  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/nDv5k/18/

Html

```
<aside>
    <div class="top">
    <h2>Product in de kijker</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
    <h3>Mobiele telefonie</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-runa">Ga verder</a>
    </div>
    <div class="upper-left"></div>
    <div class="bottom-left"></div>
    <div class="bottom-right"></div>
</aside>
```

CSS

```
aside {
    width: 290px;
    margin: 50px;
    position:relative;
}
.top{
    padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    width: 224px;
    height:75px;
    top: -1px;
}
.middle{
    padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin-top:-19px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    width: 289px;
    
}
.upper-left {
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    width:15px;
    height:25px;
    top: 0px;
    left:262px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
}
.bottom-left {
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    width:20px;
    height:25px;
    top: 25px;
    left:277px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    background:#fff;
}
.bottom-right {
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    width:35px;
    height:31px;
    top: 50px;
    left:295px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    background:#fff;
}
```

It's not a good way of coding but i didn't know another way

Using image also is not a good idea in 2013 but you can try that too..

Answer (score 0):

look into this answer:
[Div with cut out edges, border and transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030835/custom-shape-with-border-background)

my advice would be an SVG as background (as it is a vector gfx (stays crisp) and you can define how parts of it should behave when resizing).
see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css

Answer (score 0):

you pick which corner you would like to have curved. : lots of css ahead, but it will give you insights into what you can do.

css:

```
aside {
    border: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
    width: 290px;
    margin: 50px;
    position:relative;
}
.upper-left {
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    width:15px;
    height:25px;
    top: -1px;
    right:50px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
}
.bottom-left {
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    width:20px;
    height:25px;
    top: 25px;
    right:30px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    background:#fff;
}
.bottom-right {
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    width:30px;
    height:25px;
    top: 50px;
    right:-1px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    background:#fff;
}
```

html:

```
<aside>
    <h2>Product in de kijker</h2>
    <h3>Mobiele telefonie</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-runa">Ga verder</a>
    <div class="upper-left"></div>
    <div class="bottom-left"></div>
    <div class="bottom-right"></div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to add addition elements and position the borders just right.

Its a messy way of doing thing but you can achieve it.

Personally it would be easier to use a background image which you just position in the top right corner.

Hope this helps

Here is a jsFidde : http://jsfiddle.net/davidja/nDv5k/19/

```
<div class="hidelines"></div>
<div class="corner3"></div>
<div class="corner1"></div>
<div class="corner2"></div>


aside {
    position:relative; /* add relative positioning.
    border: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
    width: 290px;
    margin: 50px;
}

.corner1, .corner2, .corner3 {
    position:absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
.corner3 {
    height: 34px;
    width: 77px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
.corner1 {
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 00px;
    right: 87px;
    background: white;
    top: -1px;
}
.corner2 {
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCC00;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 00px;
    right: -1px;
    background: white;
    top: 44px;
}
.hidelines {
    position: absolute;
    right: -1px;
    top: -1px;
    height: 56px;
    width: 98px;
    background-color: white;
}
```